# System giving runtime errors and warnings while running kotlin files

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code, installation, runtime-error

I decided to learn kotlin language so I tried to install kotlin compiler form their official site and I followed all the instructions that were given on this [website](https://technology.amis.nl/software-development/quickly-get-going-with-kotlin-on-windows-using-vs-code-as-ide/) and even followed all the instruction for downloading java form [website](https://technology.amis.nl/languages/java-languages/my-steps-for-getting-started-with-java-development-on-windows/).As I wanted to setup an local (not virtual) environment in VS Code.
After setting up the environment as directed, I ran my first code.
[image: first code]

As we can see that vs code hasn't detected .kt extension(see hello.kt in image) and also gave me bunch of errors and warning I don't know what these are for and how to resolve them.
For better understanding I am also attaching my settings picture
[image: settings picture]
Please respond if you detect any flaw.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> vs code hasn't detected .kt extension(see hello.kt in image)

You can install extensions about Kotlin in marketplace to make `.kt` files get special style and be more visible.

About the warnings you said, actually it's because the kotlin-compiler itself, so they happened on my machine too, they will also be displayed in **OUTPUT** in VS Code. Your code was executed well and shows the right result.
[image]

I've tried to install `kotlin-native-windows-1.4.31.zip`, but still not that smooth and even throws the `error: invalid -include-runtime`. It seems to be an environment issue and i'll try to achieve more information. If there's any update, i'll let you know.

Comment: If you find some solutions, please don't forget to update the question:)